# parser: instruction expected on move instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to make a simple assembly program that is to add two numbers and display them, and then subtract two numbers and display them. But I'm getting there errors :

```
oppgave3.asm:28: error: parser: instruction expected
oppgave3.asm:29: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
oppgave3.asm:30: error: symbol `move' redefined
oppgave3.asm:30: error: parser: instruction expected
oppgave3.asm:31: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
oppgave3.asm:32: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
oppgave3.asm:33: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
oppgave3.asm:37: error: symbol `move' redefined
oppgave3.asm:37: error: parser: instruction expected
oppgave3.asm:38: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
oppgave3.asm:39: error: symbol `move' redefined
oppgave3.asm:39: error: parser: instruction expected
oppgave3.asm:40: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
oppgave3.asm:41: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
oppgave3.asm:42: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

This is what I'm trying to do: I have two subroutines, one for addition and one for substraction.

```
section .data
a dw 4
b dw 2


section .bss
c resb 1

section .text
global_start:
_start:

call addition
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,c
mov edx,1
int 0x80

call subtraction
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,c
mov edx,1
int 0x80

addition:
move eax,[a]
sub eax '0'
move ebx,[b]
sub ebx '0'
add eax and ebx
add eax '0'
mov [c],eax
ret

subtraction:
move eax,[a]
sub eax '0'
move ebx,[b]
sub ebx '0'
sub eax and ebx
add eax '0'
mov [c],eax
ret
```

Comment: What do you expect `add eax and ebx` to do - you probably mean `add eax, ebx` ? There are many other instructions where you have missing commas too, e.g. `sub eax '0'` which should be `sub eax, '0'`. Note also that the error messages are pretty helpful - they do seem to be telling you exactly what the problems are - try studying them more carefully.

Comment: sub ebx '0'  should be `sub ebx, '0'` no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote "move" instead of "mov"

A token not recognized as an instruction mnemonic is instead considered as a label.  Like `move nop` is equivalent to `move: nop`.  That's why you get "`symbol 'move' redefined` on some of the later uses.

There are various other syntax errors, like `sub eax and ebx` instead of `sub eax, ebx`, and a missing comma in `sub ebx '0'`

Comment: D'oh! But I'm still getting error that it needs a comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand on the subtractions and additions.

Comment: You have `sub eax and ebx`. Not sure that you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo. You have a "move" instruction whereas my guess is that it should be "mov" without the extra e at the end. I am no assembly expert, so I might be wrong here.